# Postgres SQL: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

**(Postgres)**

I'm not clear on the following: I'm selecting various fields from `STUDY_T` which may be sub-selects with aggregate functions. One independent field I'm retrieving is a LOOKUP_T join, `lookupStudyType.description`, which is not related to any aggregate functions. But I'm getting the error

```
ERROR:  column "lookupstudytype.description" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 3:     lookupStudyType.description     AS studyTypeDescription,...
```

Why do I need to also group not just by `s.id` but also `lookupStudyType.description` (while the other `s.` groupings are not required)?

```
        SELECT 
            s.id                                        AS id, 
            lookupStudyType.description                 AS studyTypeDescription, 
            s.name                                      AS name, 
            s.abbreviation                              AS abbreviation, 
            s.start_date                                AS startDate, 
            s.end_date                                  AS endDate, 
            (SELECT COUNT(r.id)   
                FILTER 
                (WHERE r.status_id IN (76, 77) ))       AS  recallCount, 
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sp.id))              AS  participantCount, 
            (SELECT MAX(r.created_date) 
                FILTER 
                (WHERE r.status_id IN (76,77) ))        AS lastRecall,
            s.login_access_required                     AS loginAccessRequired, 
            s.description                               AS description, 
            s.custom_participant_exit_message           AS customParticipantExitMessage 
        FROM study_t s 
        INNER JOIN lookup_t lookupStudyType 
           ON s.study_type_id = lookupStudyType.id 
        INNER JOIN study_staff_t ss 
            ON s.id = ss.study_id 
        INNER JOIN users_t u 
            ON ss.researcher_id = u.id 
        LEFT JOIN study_participants_t sp 
            ON s.id = sp.study_id 
        LEFT JOIN recalls_t r 
            ON r.user_id = sp.user_id 
        WHERE  u.user_name = 'test@test.com'
        GROUP BY 
            s.id
        ORDER  BY s.abbreviation ASC
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  Include that column in the `group by`.

Comment: The question is **why** . It's an independent column not related to any `STUDY_T` fields.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't know about independence of column. As a general rule for SQL, all columns must either be grouped or aggregated in aggregating queries. Some DBMS work differently however.

Comment: But then why didn't other `STUDY_T` columns need to be grouped? None of the other `s.` fields were required.

Comment: That's because the id is your primary key: A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, any column not listed in the `GROUP BY` clause should show up *aggregated* in the `SELECT` list.

For example `s.name` should show up as `max(s.name)` or `min(s.name)` since it's not present n the `GROUP BY` list. However, PostgreSQL implements **functional dependency** (a SQL Standard feature) for the `GROUP BY` clause, and detects that `s.name` is dependent in the `s.id` column (that is probably a PK); in short, there's a single possible value `s.name` for each `s.id`. Therefore, there's no need in PostgreSQL to aggregate this column (you can, but it's not needed).

On the flip side, for `lookupStudyType.description` PostgreSQL cannot determine if it's functionally dependent on `s.id` or not. You'll need to aggregate it as `max(lookupStudyType.description)` or `min(lookupStudyType.description)`, or any other aggregation expression.

As a side note, I have rarely seen functional dependency implemented in other databases. Isn't PostgreSQL awesome? (I'm not affiliated with PostgreSQL in any way).